# Can't stop Timer

Tags: c#, timer

I create a subclass of Forms.Timer, and I cannot stop this timer.

```
public class Clock : Timer
{
    private int startTime;
    private PictureBox one;
    private PictureBox two;
    private PictureBox three;

    public Clock(Size _size) : base() 
         { startTime = 0; initialComponent(_size); }
    public Clock(int start_time, Size _size) : base() 
         { startTime = start_time; initialComponent(_size); }

    public Point Location
    {
        get { return three.Location; }

        set 
        {
            three.Location = value;
            two.Location = new Point(value.X + three.Width, value.Y);
            one.Location = new Point(value.X + three.Width + two.Width, value.Y);
        }
    }

    private void initialComponent(Size _size)
    {
        ......
    }


    public void Show()
    {
        int bits = startTime % 10;
        int ten = (startTime % 100) / 10;
        int hundred = (startTime % 1000) / 100;

        one.Image = ImageLauncher.loadImage(bits, ImageLauncher.ImageType.Timer);
        two.Image = ImageLauncher.loadImage(ten, ImageLauncher.ImageType.Timer);
        three.Image = ImageLauncher.loadImage(hundred, ImageLauncher.ImageType.Timer);
    }

    protected override void OnTick(EventArgs e)
    {
        startTime++;
        if (startTime > 999 || startTime < 0) return;

        this.Show();
    }
}
```

I create an object in form's constructor, the timer can start normally, but the Stop() method doesn't work. I've tried to create a method to set Timer.Enabled to false, but it is still going, more weird is I tried to reset interval with timer.Enabled in a same method, the interval has changed but timer  still has not disbaled.

In constructor:

```
        clock = new Clock(new Size(23 * 3, 38));
```

start:

```
        if (!clock.Enabled) clock.Start();
```

method with stop:

```
private void gameOver(bool is_win)
{
    clock.Stop();
    showAll();
    string winface = is_win ? "cool" : "sad";
    ShortCutStart.Image = ImageLauncher.loadImage(winface, ImageLauncher.ImageType.Face);
    ShortCutStart.Name = winface;
}
```

Comment: did you try with this line of within `gameOver()`, `clock.Enabled = false;` (insert this above `showAll();`.

Comment: tried, any process about clock in that mehod will be run though, the onTick event would not be stopped, and enabled value is changed to true in the event.

Comment: `if (!clock.Enabled) clock.Start();` here you are starting the clock when it is not Enabled. Is this what you want? Shouldn't this be `if (clock.Enabled) clock.Start();`. i.e. Only start the clock if it is ENABLED?

Comment: _Shouldn't this be if (clock.Enabled) clock.Start();_ That would be redundant.

Comment: Should work. What's in _showAll();_?

Comment: 'coz start() is in a loop. showAll() just change some images, doesn't include any new forms.

Comment: _start() is in a loop_ Do show us the loop!

Comment: ohhh, I found the problem, start() is in the mouse click event actually, but after gameover() method. so retarded :(. Appreciate!